# How to share one method to all controllers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to share one method to all controllers with different DI, view and parameters? I need something like this:

```
public function method(Model $model)
    {
        $baseData = [
            'model' => $model,
            'route' => route('$route', [$param => $model]),
        ];

        return view($view);
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All controllers extend `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` so you can just place it there

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function method(Model $model, $route, $param, $view)
    {
        // Declared but not used
        $baseData = [
            'model' => $model,
            'route' => route($route, [$param => $model]),
        ];

        return view($view);
    }
}
```

And use it with `$this->method()`

For example in `HomeController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::first();
        return $this->method($user, 'home', 'user', 'welcome');
    }
}
```

Now accessing `domain.tld/home` will return the `welcome` view

Comment: yes, I am thinking something like this but can this be more dynamic and to call only from url and not from controller

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share function to all controller best way will make service in service folder of app.
step to make service:-

1.create service using artisan command 
php artisan make:service service_name and define function that to share to all controller in your project.

2. after making service your have to register this service with provider.make a provider using artisan command.
   php artisan make provider:provider_name and you will see 2 function register and boot
   register function is used to register your created service and boot for call already register service

register service like this

```html
public function register()
    {
         $this->app->bind('App\Services\servicename', function( $app ){
            return new serviceclassname;
        });
    }
```

3.Go config folder ,open app.php where you will get providers array. In this provider you have to define you provider like App\Providers\providerclassname::class,

4. call this service in controllers like use App\Services\serviceclassname;

```html
public function functionname(serviceclassname serviceobject)
{
  serviceobject->functionname();
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate your feedback and this sounds interesting but somehow I don't see benefits because I want to get rid of that method that I have in almost every controller.

Comment: if you want to get rid of that method that I have in almost every controller you can make helper with you function use it everywhere in all controllers. make controller in app directory by creating new folder called helper folder. where you not need to define any class just define you function. you want i can give you example how to make helpers.

Comment: thanks but it's not necessary. I still thinking how can I implement your first solution